# SQL Server Custom sorting in ORDER BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_1
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT B.ID, 'B' AS Name
    FROM tableB inner join table a inner join table c
    UNION
    SELECT A.ID, 'A' AS NAME
    FROM tableA inner join table b inner join table c
    UNION
    SELECT C.ID, 'C' AS NAME
    FROM tableC inner join table a inner join table b
    ORDER BY CASE WHEN Name = 'A' THEN '1'
          ELSE Name END ASC
END
```

The code above returns invalid column name 'Name'. Is there anyway where i can sort 'name customly by using order by without delcaring any new paramters.

Comment: Side note: [`CREATE PROCEDURE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187926.aspx): "Avoid the use of the **sp_** prefix when naming procedures. This prefix is used by SQL Server to designate system procedures"

Comment: Also consider whether you want `UNION` or `UNION ALL`. Learn the difference

Comment: I want UNION, that is what I want and sp_1 is just a name for example. The name is originally different

Comment: So you want to incur the performance impact of applying `DISTINCT`? Are there duplicates in your records? DISTINCT is not the best way to remove them

Comment: This is your second question in a row asking essentially the same thing. If people aren't understanding what you want, you perhaps need to put more work into the question. Could you add some *sample data* and your *expected results*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT B.ID, 'B' AS Name, 1 as ExplicitOrderGroup
FROM tableB inner join table a inner join table c
UNION
SELECT A.ID, 'A' AS NAME, 0 as ExplicitOrderGroup
FROM tableA inner join table b inner join table c
UNION
SELECT C.ID, 'C' AS NAME, 1 as ExplicitOrderGroup
FROM tableC inner join table a inner join table b
ORDER BY ExplicitOrderGroup, Name
```

Note, `UNION` (which behaves a bit like `DISTINCT`) will not collaps now same rows with different `ExplicitOrderGroup`. You have to determine whethere it's OK or you need some other behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use alias in order by you have to use concrete column but you can achieve this easily using common table expression for example

```
WITH MY_CTE (col1, col2, col3)
AS
-- Define the CTE query.
(
    SELECT col1, prop2 as col2, col3
    FROM table
)
-- Define the outer query referencing the CTE name.
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM MY_CTE
ORDER BY col2
GO
```

This is just an example to point u in direction

Comment: That's not entirely accurate. You can use the aliases in the order by clause, just not in a case expression in the order by clause.

Comment: sorry I meant groupby completely overlooked it. Thanks for the correction

Comment: but the result will not be what I want because the 'A' could be a different alphabet

Answer (score 0):

Can achieve this by sub-query without any new variable/parameter

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_1
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT SQ.ID, SQ.Name FROM (
        SELECT B.ID, 'B' AS Name
        FROM table B inner join table a inner join table c
        UNION
        SELECT A.ID, 'A' AS NAME
        FROM table A inner join table b inner join table c
        UNION
        SELECT C.ID, 'C' AS NAME
        FROM table C inner join table a inner join table b
    ) SQ
    ORDER BY CASE WHEN SQ.Name = 'A' THEN '1'
          ELSE SQ.Name END ASC
END
```

Comment: may i know what is SQ because it will result in multi part identifier could not be bound?

Comment: That is called as [aliases](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp). Here `SQ` is table alias.

Comment: Could you share the exact _multi part identifier_ error here

Comment: It just says that the multi part identifier  "SQ.ID, SQ.Name" could not be bound

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would add an extra column for priority.
Like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_1
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT B.ID, 'B' AS Name, 2 AS prio
    FROM tableB inner join table a inner join table c
    UNION
    SELECT A.ID, 'A' AS NAME, 1 AS prio
    FROM tableA inner join table b inner join table c
    UNION
    SELECT C.ID, 'C' AS NAME, 2 AS prio
    FROM tableC inner join table a inner join table b
    ORDER BY prio ASC, Name ASC
END
```